# Python startswith be more specific with matching

Tags: python

I am trying to check filename in Python3 like this..

```
myfilename273.zip
myfile2223.zip

if f_name.startswith('myfile') and f_name.endswith('.zip'):
    print('True')
else:
    print('False')

if f_name.startswith('myfilename') and f_name.endswith('.zip'):
    print('True')
else:
    print('False')
```

This is detecting true for both of these, is there alrternative to using startswith that will let me target more specifically?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know what you mean?? Could you provide an example of the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Well regex comes to mind:

```
filename = "myfilename273.zip"
if re.search(r'^myfile.*\.zip$', filename):
    print("MATCH")
```

This would target both of your sample filenames, because they both start with `myfile` and end in `.zip`.  If you wanted to target files beginning with `myfile`, but not `myfilename`, you could use:

```
filename = "myfile2223.zip"
if re.search(r'^myfile(?!name).*\.zip$', filename):
    print("MATCH")
```